# How would you find the maximum directional derivative in this case?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

[image: problem here (sorry, I don't know latex)]

I have gotten this down to 3a/2 + 4b/5 = 5, but now I'm stuck. Do I use the fact that the maximum directional derivative is in the direction of the gradient to set that equal (2a, b) equal to (3/5, 4/5) to find a second equation?

Comment: Yes, you can use that information to get a second equation. Check your equation. Should the first term be $\frac{6a}{5}$?

Comment: I thought it was just 3/4 * 2a?

Answer (score 1):

The directional derivative in the direction of $(\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5})$ at $(1,1)$ is given by

$$\nabla f(1,1)\cdot(\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5})=\frac{6a}{5} + \frac{4b}{5}=5\implies 6a+4b=25$$

We also know that the gradient $(2a,b)$ is in the same direction as $(\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5})$ which means, preserving ratio of rise over run, $$\frac{b}{2a}=\frac{4}{3}\implies b=\frac{8a}{3}$$

Plugging that into our first equation gives $a=\frac{3}{2}$ and $b=4$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x, y) = ax^2 + by$

Partial derivatives at $(1, 1), \frac{f(x, y)}{\partial x} = 2a, \frac{f(x, y)}{\partial y} = b$.

So gradient is $\nabla f(1,1) = (2a, b)$.

As the gradient points in the direction of the max directional derivative,

$\sqrt{4a^2 + b^2} = 5$ (pls note that the max directional derivative is same as the magnitude of the gradient).

And unit vector which is the direction of max directional derivative is

$(\frac{2a}{\sqrt{4a^2 + b^2}}, \frac{b}{\sqrt{4a^2 + b^2}}) = (\frac{3}{5}, \frac{4}{5})$.

And that gives value of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The directional derivative is $5$, not the magnitude of the gradient.

Comment: @JohnDouma it is maximum directional derivative and so will be same as the magnitude of gradient.